# Linking custom container on wercker

Tags: php, docker, continuous-integration, containers, wercker

I create a container in docker and with id/name i

```
box: ujwaldhakal/laravel
build:
  steps:
    - install-packages:
        packages: git
    - script:
        name: install phpunit
        code: |-
          curl -L https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar -o /usr/local/bin/phpunit
          chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpunit
    - script:
        name: install composer
        code: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    - script:
        name: install dependencies
        code: composer install --no-interaction
    - script:
        name: PHPUnit integration tests
        code: phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml
```

box ujwaldhakal/laravel won't work if used php it will work. There were no any good docs for linking the custom container on wercker.

Comment: What errors do you get with the laravel box?

Comment: No such image found

Comment: Is the `ujwaldhakal/laravel` container on the Docker Hub? That's where Wercker is looking for it.

Comment: Yeah... the documentation isn't much help in the way of troubleshooting :-(

Answer (score 0):

### Short Version

Have you tried adding a tag after the box id? That solved the issue for me under similar circumstances. Otherwise the image has not (yet) been built and/or pushed to Docker Hub.

### Long Version

I had a similar problem. I wanted to use the [`dealerdirect/ci-php` box](https://hub.docker.com/r/dealerdirect/ci-php/)

So I changed my `wercker.yml` to use it:

```
box:
  id: dealerdirect/ci-php
# ...
```

But then the build failed:

[image: screenshot of failing build]

The "setup environment" step had the error "no such image":

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

After some experimenting it turned out I needed to add a "tag":

```
box:
  id: dealerdirect/ci-php:5.6
# ...
```

After that the docker image was pulled fine and the build continued working again:

[image]

Of course, this only works if the images actually *exists* on Docker Hub. If it does not, you will have to push it manually or set up automated building.